# Keep Google Home test app alive longer than 29 min

Tags: google-home

Has anyone found a way to keep Google Home apps you've developed alive for longer than 29min? My app is only reachable on the actual device if I'm actively developing for it. So literally to interact with it I need to have pushed a command to it within the last 29min. When setting the invocation name

```
  ./gactions preview -action_package=action.json -invocation_name="wake up word"
```

I get back this message:

```
Pushing action 'wake up word' for testing...
'wake up word' is now available for you until 2017-05-03 4:57PM CDT (29 minutes from now)
```

If I attempt to invoke it after that timeline, its not reachable. Kinda sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a preview flag to the command.

```
 ./gactions preview -action_package=action.json -preview_mins=999999999 -invocation_name="wake up word"
```

-preview_mins=999999999 effectively sets it for 2000 years.